# Can't access merge fields in email template

Tags: apex, email, email-template, sharing, org-wide-defaults

We have a custom object XYZ whose OWD is set to private. In our salesforce community we have an apex class declared with the `without sharing` keyword as a result we are able to access records owned by other user.

In the `targetObjectId` I have specified the ID of the record which the logged in user doesn't own and when i try to send mail using `sendmail()`, it gives me the error `INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY`

i want to know why `sendmail()` isn't working inside a class declared `without sharing` since we have access to that record.

Comment: There can be other reasons of this error. If you can post the code you are using and which object are referenced then it would be helpful to find the reason.

Comment: also, when i change the OWD to public read only for that object the mail is successfully getting sent.

Comment: Using visualforce template mail is getting sent. But it is still not working with an HTML Email template.